# Android_Studio_error_file_error_ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.aromproject6, PID: 13385
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aromproject6/com.example.aromproject6.StartActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.aromproject6.StartActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~gSEQsY1NRFD7fu96ddB6lA==/com.example.aromproject6--sMR1Ru1-lfEOAG_4i260A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~gSEQsY1NRFD7fu96ddB6lA==/com.example.aromproject6--sMR1Ru1-lfEOAG_4i260A==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3613)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3864)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2253)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7870)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.aromproject6.StartActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~gSEQsY1NRFD7fu96ddB6lA==/com.example.aromproject6--sMR1Ru1-lfEOAG_4i260A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~gSEQsY1NRFD7fu96ddB6lA==/com.example.aromproject6--sMR1Ru1-lfEOAG_4i260A==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1285)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3600)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3864) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2253) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7870) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

I have problems.. help me...
I don't know why my laptop has errors.
I can't Run any codes.

i try clean project alot.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**My answer was correct. I received her project and solve the issue manually. She had not asked proper questions related to that issues.**

This error shows that

[image]

This error indicates that the compiler can't find your class Path /Package Name...

**"com.example.aromproject6.StartActivity"**

Please follow the below steps:

1. check **StartActivity** may have the correct package Name.?
2. check the package and class Name in your AndroidManifest.xml file match the package and class name?
3. Check app Build correctly?
4. The app may not have been installed correctly: If you are running the app on a device or emulator, ensure that it has been compatible with to build version.

You don't have selected the `StartActivity` to run the project...

Please go to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and apply the following changes:

[image]

If it's still not working please share your project with me. I try my best to solve your issue

Comment: i add your code.. but it doesnt work :(

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Images are fine to _supplement_ answers, but answers should always stand on their own without images.

Comment: Share your project with me. I try my best to solve your issue

Comment: which medium you are using for chating

Comment: u can see the project on this link

Comment: https://github.com/Munhangyeol/AromProject6

Comment: lets me checked

Comment: I'm Checking your project

Comment: How i i sahre with you

Comment: umm.. csh991414@naver.com here's my email send any email plz.

Comment: code link
Hy!
here is Error Free code

https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20230405MtqG5ZSw